# Is there a possible race condition in tis code, and why?

Tags: c++, race-condition

I have the below code:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <memory>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <mutex>
#include <deque>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "third_party/concurrentqueue.h"

struct Dummy {
    std::string name_;
};

class Consumer {
public:
    Consumer() {
        is_running_ = true;
        data_thread_ = std::unique_ptr<std::thread>(
            new std::thread(&Consumer::listening, this));
    }

    void push(std::shared_ptr<Dummy> frame)
    {
        nice_queue.enqueue(frame);
    }

    virtual void listening() {
        while (is_running_) {
            std::shared_ptr<Dummy> frame;
            if (nice_queue.try_dequeue(frame)) {
                // Is there a possible race condition,
                // as there is no memory fence?
                std::cout << frame->name_ << std::endl; // <<<<<<
            }
        }
    }

    std::unique_ptr<std::thread> data_thread_;
    moodycamel::ConcurrentQueue<std::shared_ptr<Dummy>> nice_queue;
    std::atomic<bool> is_running_;
};

class Producer {
public:
    Producer(std::shared_ptr<Consumer> consumer)
    :consumer_(consumer){}

    void send(std::shared_ptr<Dummy> frame) {
        consumer_->push(frame);
    }

protected:
    std::shared_ptr<Consumer> consumer_;
};

int main() {
    std::shared_ptr<Consumer> consumer = std::make_shared<Consumer>();
    Producer prod(consumer);
    for(int i =0; i<100; i++){
        auto item = std::make_shared<Dummy>();
        item->name_ = std::to_string(i);
        prod.send(item);
    }
}
```

As the code shows, the `Producer` sends an item to the `Consumer` to be processed in another thread, so two things happen strictly one after another, but due to there being no memory fence, is there a possibility that when `Consumer` processes the item, it doesn't see the final version of the item, and thus has undefined behaviour?

Comment: Is there's no synchronization in `moodycamel::ConcurrentQueue`? If there isn't, it should change its name.

Comment: What is the semantic of `enqueue` and `dequeue`?

Comment: but what i am passing through the queue is a shared_ptr

Comment: `enqueue` will make a copy, `dequeue` will give a reference

Comment: Impossible to answer, since it depends on what the implementation of `moodycamel::ConcurrentQueue`  (which is not a standard type) does, and you haven't specified that.   `shared_ptr` does not inherently ensure appropriate synchronisation if it, or its pointee, is accessed concurrently - code using it needs to take care of synchronisation.

Comment: @Peter the administration of the shared_ptr is synchronized, however accessing the pointee not (as you wrote) (from cppreference: To satisfy thread safety requirements, the reference counters are typically incremented using an equivalent of std::atomic::fetch_add with std::memory_order_relaxed (decrementing requires stronger ordering to safely destroy the control block).

Answer (score 2):

The synchronization is happening under the hood in the `moodycamel::ConcurrentQueue`.
As the name (and the documentation) suggests, it's a thread safe queue. So it can be written&read from different threads concurrently.

[moodyCamel doc](https://github.com/cameron314/concurrentqueue#features)

The fact that you are sending `shared_ptr`s is not impacting anything here.